# WSO2 EBS- WSDL Proxy- 2 Ports

Tags: proxy, wsdl, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

We want to create a WSDL proxy on WSO2 ESB. The WSDL has 2 ports defined, each port defines its own
operations.
The problem is when I create the WSDL proxy and specify one of the port, the operation associated with that port is not exposed, rather the operation associated with  port 2 is exposed... looks like no matter which port I point to, the operation exposed doesnt change..
My question is how can i make this work, or multiple ports in WSDL is not supported by WSO2 ESB ?

```
......
<wsdl:portType name="IxxxxService">
    <wsdl:operation name="xxxRecordEntry">
        <wsdl:input
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IxxxService/xxxRecordEntry"
            message="tns:IxxxService_xxxRecordEntry_InputMessage" />
        <wsdl:output
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IxxxService/xxxRecordEntryResponse"
            message="tns:IxxxService_xxxRecordEntry_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="xxxRecord">
        <wsdl:input
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IxxxServiceMoniker/xxxRecord"
            message="tns:IxxxServiceMoniker_xxxRecord_InputMessage" />
        <wsdl:output
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IxxxServiceMoniker/xxxRecordResponse"
            message="tns:IxxxServiceMoniker_xxxRecord_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:portType name="IxxxServiceMoniker">
    <wsdl:operation name="xxxRecord">
        <wsdl:input
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IxxxMoniker/xxxRecord"
            message="tns:IxxxServiceMoniker_xxxRecord_InputMessage" />
        <wsdl:output
            wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IxxxServiceMoniker/xxxRecordResponse"
            message="tns:IxxxServiceMoniker_xxxRecord_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IxxxService"
    type="tns:IxxxService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="xxxRecordEntry">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IxxxService/xxxRecordEntry"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IxxxMoniker"
    type="tns:IxxxMoniker">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="xxxRecord">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IxxxMoniker/xxxRecord"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="xxxService">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IxxxService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IxxxService">
        <soap:address location="http://aaaaa:pppp/xxxService.xxxService.svc"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IxxxServiceMoniker" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IxxxServiceMoniker">
        <soap:address location="http://aaaaa:pppp/xxxService.xxxService.svc/mo"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Proxy Configuration

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="testing20" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
<target>
  <outSequence>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
  <endpoint>
     <wsdl service="xxxService" port="BasicHttpBinding_IxxxService" uri="http://xxx:ppp/xxxLoggerService.xxxService.svc?wsdl"/>
  </endpoint>
</target>
<publishWSDL uri="http://xxx:ppp/xxxLoggerService.xxxService.svc?wsdl"/>
<parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
<parameter name="modifyUserWSDLPortAddress">true</parameter>
<description></description>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your proxy configuration? And which operations caused issue?
When you create proxy, you can disable unwanted bindings.That is, you can disable soap11 or soap12.

```
eg:<parameter name="disableSOAP12">true</parameter>
```

Comment: -added proxy confg in post. 1.The proxy points to BasicHttpBinding_IxxxService port hence should be able to service the associated xxxRecordEntry operation. 2. When I send webservice request with WS-Action as xxxRecordEntry operation the ESB shows me an error that EPR is invalid. 3. When I use 'tryIt' on this proxy the operation that is shown is xxxRecord which is actually associated with second port BasicHttpBinding_IxxxServiceMoniker which my proxy doesnt point to  4. The behavior is same when i switch the port in my proxy i.e. it still shows xxxRecord as the available operation